# Angular doesn't return inner nested for loops

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop

I'm trying to make a for loop script that creates orders using Angular and adds it to a webpage. I'm having trouble with this certain for loops because when I use console.log(), it only outputs the outer loops and not the inner loops. And I need to pass the variable order to another function so that's why I need the order to have the correct data.

```
var order;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 52; i += 1) {
        if (i <= 32) {
            order = "500200000" + i;
            element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
            if (i >= 10) {
                order = "50020000" + i;
                element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
            }
        } else if (i == 33) {
            for (var a = 1; a <= 30; a += 1) {
                order = "69200000" + a;
                element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
                if (i >= 10) {
                    order = "6920000" + a;
                    element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
                }
            }
            order = "5002000033";
            element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
        }
        console.log(order);
 };
```

Results:

```
5002000001
5002000002
5002000003
5002000004
5002000005
5002000006
5002000007
5002000008
5002000009
5002000010
5002000011
5002000012
5002000013
5002000014
5002000015
5002000016
5002000017
5002000018
5002000019
5002000020
5002000021
5002000022
5002000023
5002000024
5002000025
5002000026
5002000027
5002000028
5002000029
5002000030
5002000031
5002000032
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
5002000033
```

It repeats the last outer loop value and doesn't output the inner one. I'm still quite new to Javascript so I need some insight and a solution and maybe simple way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

write the console.log inside the inner loop body to view the result of the inner loop

Answer (score 0):

following should work:

```
var order;
for (var i = 1; i <= 52; i += 1) {
    if (i <= 32) {
        order = "500200000" + i;
        element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
        if (i >= 10) {
            order = "50020000" + i;
            element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
        }
    } else if (i == 33) {
        for (var a = 1; a <= 30; a += 1) {
            order = "69200000" + a;
            element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
            if (i >= 10) {
                order = "6920000" + a;
                element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
            }



            // ** add here a console.log output e.g.**
            console.log('inner loop: ' + order);



        }
        order = "5002000033";
        element(by.model("order")).clear().sendKeys(order);
    }
    console.log(order);
};
```